# How to mount local folder to the Kubernetes cluster created by Rancher Desktop?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancher-desktop

When I use k3d create a Kubernetes cluster, I can mount local folder `/Users/me/data` to the cluster `/data` using `volume`

```
k3d cluster create west --config=k3d-config.yaml
```

**k3d-config.yaml**

```
apiVersion: k3d.io/v1alpha3
kind: Simple
kubeAPI:
  host: "k8s-example.com"
  hostIP: "127.0.0.1"
  hostPort: "6440"
network: hm-network
volumes:
  - volume: "/Users/me/data:/data"  # <- this line helps mount
ports:
  - port: 40000:80
    nodeFilters:
      - loadbalancer
options:
  k3s:
    extraArgs:
      - arg: --cluster-domain=west.k8s-example.com
        nodeFilters:
          - server:*
```

Now I am using the Kubernetes cluster created by Rancher Desktop and hoping to do the same thing.

I am on macOS, and I found [this document](https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/provisioning-scripts#macos--linux) which seems right document (?):

> On macOS and Linux, you can use lima override.yaml to write provisioning scripts.
>
> `~/Library/Application Support/rancher-desktop/lima/_config/override.yaml`
>
> You can also use override.yaml to override/modify a lima configuration
> setting, for example, to create additional mounts as shown below.
>
> ```
>  mounts:
>   - location: /some/path 
>     writable: true
> ```

However, I am not entirely sure how to use this to mount my local folder `/Users/me/data` to the cluster `/data`.

Any guide would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You can mount it as a hostpath inside a Pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data
      name: some-path
  volumes:
  - name: some-path
    hostPath:
      path: /some/path
      type: Directory
```